# How to return data from php to the page using http post AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

My AngularJs page

```
  var postContactFn = function($http,data){
        return $http.post("myfirstfile.php", data);
    }

mainModule.factory('postContact',['$http',postContactFn]);
```

//In my controller

```
    postContactFn(data).success(function(data, status) {
        if(data){
                  console.log('success');
          }
    }
```

Php page MyFirstFile.php

```
 <?php
$name = $_POST['inputUsername']; 
if(!empty($name)){
  --send mail
 echo 'success'
}
```

Here the mail is been sent to my id but I'm not getting redirected back the controller. Instead it is showing success on my page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated..
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the data as dependency, not to a function.

This is how it should be:

```
mainModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, postContact) {
  postContact.postData(data).then(function(data)) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And your factory:

```
mainModule.factory('postContact', function($http) {
  return {
    postData : function(data) {
      return $http.post("myfirstfile.php", data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: okay but still it doesn't come back the controller it goes to the php file and shows success string on the browser. But actually it should get call backed in that controller.

Comment: I don't understand. what should call back in the controller?

Comment: I expect this should happen Controller -----> Factory----->PHP----on success--->Controller console.log('success')   but on success php isn't passing to controller

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/RrneW4DM73Ay4xpsdJKj?p=preview

This is the link but there are some other errors

Comment: Is it working for you now? the plunkr looking good but you need to handle error like this: postData(data).then(function(data){...}, function(error) {...});

Comment: Yes, It works now I had problems in both sides in php I was suppose to get the json data in the following formate
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
and your approach gave me a clear cut idea.. Thank you
$name =  $request->inputUsername;